# Как узнать нормаль поверхности на которой стоит персонаж в Unity 2D?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть персонаж:

[image]

Мне нужно найти нормаль или нормали на которых он стоит, сейчас использую один raycast, но он не всегда подходит(как тут):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И тут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И мне нужно другой способ(например находить точки коллизии) или просто выпускать его в правильном месте.

Comment: Рейкастить можно те только лучи, но и формы, как боксы, сферы, капсулы в целях наблюдения на перед, но по факту произошедшего ничего искать не нужно поскольку в [Collision](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision.html) предоставляемые методами `OnCollision...`, как не странно есть и точки и нормале и ваще ВСЕ.

Comment: @Yaroslav, но как мне определить какая кочка коллизии коллизия с землёй, а какая со стеной лил потолком?
Но кажется я придумал что можно сделать.

Comment: А определить  по `y` оси нормали религия запрещает? Если она меньше нуля... мамой клянусь это не пол! если только он не на поталке... через `aSin(y)` можно даже угол узнать.